# Search in the repos matching a previous query in github advanced search

Tags: github, github-search

I'm using github advanced search with the code query `path:*.agda-lib  cubical AND NOT is:fork`.

I want to do a subsequent code query restricted to within all the *repos* that had code that matched my first query. I could of course manually copy all the repo names manually but I'd prefer not to do that.